# How to reset number of retrys on Autosys job

Tags: autosys

I have a list of jobs that have number of retrys set on them (in jil definition). When I get the job status, I see the number of retrys (in this case 12). I am trying to find a way to reset that:

->autorep -J XXXXX%

Job Name Last Start Last End ST Run/Ntry Pri/Xit

XXXXXX 03/19/2014 14:27:38 03/19/2014 14:56:07 SU 146461/12 0

More details:
I am setting n_retrys: 15 in my job definition so I am aware of that. However, as the job runs (it runs 24 hrs a day), it occasionally fails so after a few days, number of retries gets close to be exceeded in which case job will no longer automatically restart when it fails. I am looking for a way to reset the retry count to zero.

Comment: I think it is possible to write a script (in bash or python) that resets `retry = 0; when Job Status='SU'`